# Unexpected output from Bash for loop using curly brackets

Tags: linux, bash

I expected the following loop to print numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Basic range in for loop
for value in {1..5}
do
    echo $value
done
```

but I get the following output in a single line:
{1..5}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: most likely you are running the script wrongly, for ex: `sh script.sh`..

Comment: How are you running your script?

Comment: [different ways to run bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/300/hello-world/1136/hello-world#t=201609190352481927018)

Comment: yes, sh script.sh
Is that the wrong way?

Comment: yes, your script is written in `bash` but you are running it as `sh` script which is a different scripting language... see the link I posted for details...

Comment: thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

`{1..5}` won't necessarily work like you expect it to in every circumstance. A better way to do this (to my mind, at least) is to use `seq`:

```
for value in $(seq 1 5)
do
    echo $value
done
```

`seq` is a simple program included in basically every Unix that generates the sequence of numbers dictated by its two arguments.

Comment: For `bash`: Using `seq` for this is overkill. It is wasting a process, for something that is built-in. Use `seq` only if one of them (1 or 5) is a variable. For `sh`: there is no simpler option than `seq`.

Comment: @Sebastian thanks for the suggestion. I knew about the seq but I wasn't sure why the curly brackets didn't work.

Comment: With bash, the better practice is `for ((i=1; i<5; i++)); do echo "$i"; done`. `seq` is not built into bash, and it is not part of the POSIX specification. There is no guarantee it will exist at all, and if it _does_ exist, there is no guarantee it will behave any particular way.